# nvd3 TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am having an issue with nvd3 line chart graph. Sometimes graph is showing without labels and lines. it only shows points. but sometimes the same data is generating with labels and lines. This will happen when i continuously refreshing or changing the data. issue image,
[image]

Console shows below issues,

[image]

**UPDATE :**

nvd3 chart generator code

```
var option = {
                chart: {
                    lines: {
                        dispatch: {
                            elementClick: function (e, scope) {
                                console.log(e.data);     
                            } 
                        },
                    },
                    "type": "lineChart",
                    "height": 400, 
                    "tooltip": {
                        contentGenerator: function (key, x, y, e, graph) {
                            return  'test' 
                            }  
                     },
                    "showLegend": false,
                    "margin": {
                        top: 50,
                        right: 50,
                        bottom: 60,
                        left: 100
                    }, 
                    "dispatch": {},
                    xAxis: {
                        "tickSize": 1,
                        "axisLabelDistance": 1,
                        "showMaxMin": false,
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        axisLabelDistance: -5,
                        tickPadding: 10,  
                    },
                    reduceXTicks: false,
                    useInteractiveGuideline: false
                }  
            };
```

Some one help to resolve this issue, 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please show some code?

Comment: @ofey chart option code is updated. please check

Comment: Sorry I don't recognise this way of doing things. I'd usually see data in for example json and js, d3 code separated. Maybe it's done differently in nvd3. I've only used d3. I don't see any of the examples on nvd3 site that look like this. What you've shown is an object. Perhaps you could show your code.

Comment: Any chance you could create a JSFiddle with your code? I usually have an explicit function for x and y properties. Something like `{ x: function (data) { return +data.x; }, y: function (data) { return +data.y; } }` but that's primarily because I have a lot of stringified numbers in my dataset.